# Erlang tuple: Iterating over tuple

Tags: erlang

I need to iterate a tuple in Erlang.

So basically I have a list of tuples `Tuple = [{Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6}],`. I don't know how many items are in the tuple. (And those VarN may be quite complex, and may be tuples or lists).

And I would need to create a new `Tuple2` by iterating `Tuple` and changing all these variables. So basically I need something similar to `lists:map`

Comment: `tuple_to_list/1` + `lists:map/2` + `list_to_tuple/1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `tuple_to_list`, `lists:map` and `list_to_tuple` to achieve what you want.

Here is an example (written for elrang shell)

```
8> Add1 = fun(M) -> M+1 end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.6.50752066>
9> list_to_tuple(lists:map(Add1, tuple_to_list({1, 2, 3}))).
{2,3,4}
```

You can easily extend the above to work on a list of tuple.